# How to format a Date with Luxon?

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

With moment.js, you can format a date this way:

```js
const date = moment("2010-10-22T21:38:00");
const data = date.format("LL - LT") 
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Izh34nqeeR7/nwthfeE0SI3c8uhFSnqxV0sI9TvTcXiFJkMd6fB644O64BRq2P/LA/+7eRvCw4GmLsXksyTHBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How to do the same thing with Luxon? I've tried:

```js
const date = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2010-10-22T21:38:00" );
const data = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(date, "DATETIME_SHORT")
// output => script error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
const date = DateTime.fromISO("2010-10-22T21:38:00")
const humanReadable = date.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_MED);

console.log(humanReadable); // =>  October 22, 9:38 PM
```

Source: https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/formatting.md

You can read more about the possible formats here: https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/formatting.md#the-basics

Comment: The links are not working any more.
Here is an updated version: https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/formatting.md

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: DateTime is not defined

Comment: @oO. Have you referenced to the luxon instance? like so: `const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;` or `const { DateTime } = require("luxon");`

Comment: https://moment.github.io/luxon/demo/global.html
Passionate developers created a lot of examples. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const newDate = DateTime.fromISO(value)
    .setLocale(LuxonSettings.defaultLocale)
    .toLocaleString('datetimeFull');
```

You can find extra examples for Luxon here:
https://moment.github.io/luxon/demo/global.html

And extra date formats here:
https://www.jsdocs.io/package/@types/luxon